# My object becomes empty when do JSON.stringfy

Tags: javascript, object, local-storage

I have an object which i want to set to the localstorage. But everytime it pushes the object with empty value. When i print it in the console it shows the data properly. se below images

my code

```
const ProductAttribute = {
      productID: productID,
      Attributes: { [this.name]: productAttrState || this.activeItemIndex },
    };

    console.log(ProductAttribute);

    localStorage.setItem(
      this.localStorageName,
      JSON.stringify(ProductAttribute)
    );
```

here is the console output
[image: console]

here is the localstorage output

[image: localstograge]

As you can see my Attributes data does not shows.

Comment: doesn't look empty ... it has a productID ... it's only the attributes that are empty ... what is the result if you `console.log(JSON.stringify(ProductAttribute))` just after you `console.log(ProductAttribute)` - perhaps your actual code is a little more complex and you've removed some important piece of code that would explain this impossible result?

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(ProductAttribute)) -> it gives the same result as console but in json version. But localstorage attributes is empty. and i gave the same function that i used in my code

Comment: if the code is exactly as you've shown - then that's impossible - and the "localStorage output" should also be JSON, not an object like you've shown - what is the output of `console.log(localStorage.getItem(this.localStorageName))` if you add that directly after the `setItem` code? by the way, these suggestions of `console.log` are basic debugging I would've expected you to already try

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have already tried that -> console.log(localStorage.getItem(this.localStorageName)). It shows the output with attribute data, but it is not showing in the local storage. Why on earth does it behave like this.